# How to change background color of child preference screen in honeycomb

Tags: android

I have been searching for the solution for the last several days but could not find one.

I need to change the background color of the right pane (I know how to change the color of the left parent preference). I created a new theme in manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".PreferenceWithHeaders"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme">
</activity>
```

Below is the PreferencesTheme portion of styles.xml

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

I am, however, unable to change the default gray background color of the child  `PreferenceScreen`which is on the right. Please take a look at the picture.

[image: PreferenceScreen Illustration]

I tried different things but they don't have any impact on the background color. Any pointers will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Just find this link here, I hope this may help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571603/change-preferenceactivity-text-color

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I tried both the options. The first option changes the color of the left pane which I was able to do before. The second option can change the background colors of elements of PreferenceScreen like title etc. It was not able to change the background, however.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue not long ago; couldn't figure it out at the time, even after trying many of the solutions here.  Finally stumbled upon a fix after running into a similar issue.

I just finished writing a blog post about it that explains in more detail, [Fixing empty white space issues with Android ListViews](http://wordpress.badwaterstudios.com/android-listview-background-fill-and-empty-space/), but basically you should be able to get rid of the white space by setting `overScrollFooter` to `@null`.

As overScrollFooter is only available in Android 2.3.3+ (API Level 10+), you'd have something like this:

res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
</style>
```

res/**values-v10**/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:overScrollFooter">@null</item>
</style>
```

And of course update your PreferencesTheme to use it:

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
</style>
```