# Android: PreferenceActivity Extra White Space Below Items

Tags: android, background, styles, preferenceactivity

All,

I am new to using the PreferenceActivity and ended up getting it to work. However, the issue I am having is that there is an ugly white space after my preference items. I tried applying a style and setting the background color to black. However, this did not work. Any help would be appreciated. I attached some code and a screenshot below.

Thx

```
public class EditPref extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

}
```

}

The style xml code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="editPref">
       <item name = "android:background">#FF000000</item>





    </style>

</resources>
```

attached is the preference xml file.

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkbox"
        android:title="Checkbox Preference"
        android:summary="Check it on, check it off" />
    <RingtonePreference
        android:key="ringtone"
        android:title="Ringtone Preference"
        android:showDefault="true"
        android:showSilent="true"

        android:summary="Pick a tone, any tone" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I am developing for API 10.

[image]

Comment: Could you also attach preferences.xml file contents and tell us which Android version you're running this on?

Comment: Done. Please see original question.

Comment: Theres a certain phone. Unfortunately, I can't remember which one :( that overwrites listviews to have that grey hatching instead of a background if the elements don't fill the screen. Its gross, I know. Have you tried this on another phone?

Comment: I mean a normal listview does not do this.

Comment: @HannahMitt It's the Motorola devices running Gingerbread. That pesky MotoBlur interface messes it up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your Activity declaration look like in the ActivityManifest.xml?  More specifically, what theme are you using?  I posted a solution to a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417111/how-to-change-background-color-of-child-preference-screen-in-honeycomb/10885472#10885472), but basically you should be able to get rid of the ugly white space by setting `overScrollFooter` to `@null` for your ListViews on API Level 10+.

I was having the same issue and just wrote a [blog post](http://wordpress.badwaterstudios.com/android-listview-background-fill-and-empty-space/) with a little more detail, but try using this (substituting the theme you're using for the parent, of course):

res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
</style>
```

res/values-v10/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:overScrollFooter">@null</item>
</style>
```

Set your theme to use the new ListView style:

```
<style name="Theme.MyPreferences" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
</style>
```

And in your AndroidManifest.xml, declare the EditPref Activity to use the new theme.  Something along the lines of:

```
<activity
    android:name=".EditPref"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyPreferences" />
```