# Android set background color of preference category

Tags: android, background-color, preferenceactivity

I try to customize the background color of preference categories. I already changed the background color of a preferences itself but I can't find a way how to change the the categories background color.

I found two ways but they don't works for me:
[changing the preference category label color background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048089/changing-the-preference-category-label-color-background)

Through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571603/change-preferenceactivity-text-color), i found [this](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/dress-up-your-preferenceactivity/), but nothing I've tried worked for me. These layout snippet is what I've tried so far:

```
<resources>
    <style name="setBackgroundTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/darkbluelogo</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In `onCreate` method I set the theme with:

```
setTheme(R.style.setBackgroundTheme);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom a layout file with your background color, set it in your PreferenceCategory:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:layout="@layout/your_layout">
```